# Executing a DateTime method in Main

Tags: c#, class, datetime, methods

I need to make a simple program that asks you to press a button twice, once to start the timer and second time to stop it, then it has to show you the difference in seconds from the moment you pressed these buttons, yet I can't figure out a way to write the code in Main. I think my class `Stoper` is made properly, but I am not really sure.

I've tried different ways to use `ReadKey` to assign the starting `DateTime` to a variable.

```
class Stoper
{
    DateTime czas_zakonczenia;
    DateTime czas;
    DateTime czas_rozpoczecia;

    private DateTime Czas_rozpoczecia
    {
        get
        {
            return Czas_rozpoczecia;
        }
    }

    public DateTime Start(DateTime czas_rozpoczecia)
    {
        return czas_rozpoczecia = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime Stop(DateTime czas_zakonczenia)
    {
        return czas_zakonczenia = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public void WyswietlCzas()
    {
        var czas = (Start(czas_rozpoczecia) - Stop(czas_zakonczenia)).TotalSeconds;

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kliknij dowolony przycisk gdy chcesz zaczac pomiar czasu.");
        Stoper s1 = new Stoper(Start());
    }
}
```

Comment: ``czas = (czas_rozpoczecia - czas_zakonczenia).TotalSeconds``. Or ``czas = (czas_rozpoczecia - Stop(czas_zakonczenia).TotalSeconds``. It depends on what u need.

Comment: `Stoper s1 = new Stoper(); 
Console.Read(); 
s1.Start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom class for that. You can use the [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) class. Try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the timer");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine("Timer started. Press any key to stop");
    Console.ReadKey();

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("The timer has stopped.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time is: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

If you have to use a custom class. There are some irrelevant variables in your class and the logic is also incorrect. You may rewrite your class into something like this: <sup>(feel free to translate the variables/method names into your language)</sup>

```
class Stoper
{
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }

    private DateTime startDate;

    public void Start()
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        ElapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startDate;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in the same way the `StopWatch` class is used above:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the timer");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Stoper s1 = new Stoper();
    s1.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Timer started. Press any key to stop");
    Console.ReadKey();

    s1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("The timer has stopped.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time is: {s1.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds} seconds.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The point is - I need to do that with a custom class and methods.

Comment: @Wurfv_ I updated the answer with an example of a custom "Stopper" class.

Comment: And yet, *no* explanation as to why the OP code wasn't working? If these details were included, it would help the OP and or anyone else coming along with the same issue, know what the problem was and how it can be addressed.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't need to, just adding some constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the timer.\n");
    Console.ReadKey();

    stopWatch.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the timer.\n");
    Console.ReadKey();

    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed seconds: {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code:

---

This causes a stack overflow. Because you use the property (with the capital C), where you want to use the field (with the small c). C# is case sensitive.

```
    private DateTime Czas_rozpoczecia
    {
        get
        {
            return Czas_rozpoczecia; 
        }
    }
```

You probably want this:

```
    private DateTime Czas_rozpoczecia
    {
        get
        {
            return czas_rozpoczecia; 
            //     ^ Small letter
        }
    }
```

Or even this:

```
    private DateTime Czas_rozpoczecia => czas_rozpoczecia;
```

---

You use an argument with the same name as the field? Then you assign a value (to the argument?) and forget about it.

```
    public DateTime Start(DateTime czas_rozpoczecia)
    {
        return czas_rozpoczecia = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

You probably want to use it like this. Store the current DateTime in the field. And you should fix this for the `Stop` method as well.

```
    public DateTime Start()
    {
        czas_rozpoczecia = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

---

The difference between two DateTimes is a TimeSpan, and there's no use to store it, since you have all fields already.

```
    public Double WyswietlCzas()
    {
        return (czas_rozpoczecia - czas_zakonczenia).TotalSeconds;

    }
}
```

---

Now fix the main code. Use `ReadKey` to wait for a key. And call the methods using the instance (`s1`) you just created.

```
        var s1 = new Stoper();
        Console.ReadKey();
        s1.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        s2.Stop();
```

---

And you should be able to figure out how to print the seconds yourself.

Comment: Thanks for *explaining* the OP issue and how to address it.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Using the Stopwatch class does not teach the OP to program.

Comment: it's not *just* about the `Stopwatch` class; I didn't say it was. My point is you explained the OP issue's they had in code, this give's them an understanding of what they did wrong, followed with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Start Timer");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("\nTimer Started");
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Stop Timer");
        Console.ReadKey();
        var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        var sb = "\n" + (stopTime - startTime);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
```